# How can I edit labels in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm practicing to code indicators using pine script. To practice I traying to create all in one indicator with combining MA and EMA lines. I label the all MA/EMA lines to recognize easily. when I go to indicator settings I can tick/untick all MA/EMA lines separately. But can't hide labels separately. how can I tick/untick my **labels separately**?

```
/ Define the EMA13 line
ema_13 = ta.ema(close,13)

// Define the EMA8 line
ema_8 = ta.ema(close,8)


/ Plot the EMA13 line
plot(ema_13, color = color.lime, linewidth = 2, title = "13 EMA")

// Plot the EMA8 line
plot(ema_8, color = color.maroon, linewidth = 2, title = "8 EMA")


// Label the EMA13 line
ema13l = label.new(bar_index, ema_13, text = "EMA13", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color.lime, style = label.style_none,textcolor = color.gray)
label.delete(ema13l[1])

// Label the EMA8 line
ema8l = label.new(bar_index, ema_8, text = "EMA8", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color.maroon, style = label.style_none,textcolor = color.gray)
label.delete(ema8l[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you will need to add an input to allow the user to switch labels on/off.

   `showLabel = input.bool(true, 'show Labels')`
2. Switch your last line(s) from

   ```
   // Label the EMA8 line
   ema8l = label.new(bar_index, ema_8, text = "EMA8", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color.maroon, style = label.style_none,textcolor = color.gray)
   label.delete(ema8l[1])
   ```

   to

   ```
   // Label the EMA8 line
   if showLabel
       ema8l = label.new(bar_index, ema_8, text = "EMA8", xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color.maroon, style = label.style_none,textcolor = color.gray)
       label.delete(ema8l[1])
   ```

I will share a more comprehensive answer after launch.